# Java methods with large number of parameters

Tags: java

I am currently writing a small program in java that scores a word guess against a word answer (Think Wordle). I am writing test cases in JUNIT and am finding I am repeating a lot of code. I thought to make a method, but realized it would be passing a lot of parameters for each testcase. I was wondering what the best practice would be. Do I keep the repetitive code, do I use a method with 10+ parameters, or is there a more elegant solution?

Example code:

```
                Letter letter = g1.getLetter('A');
                assertEquals('A', letter.getLett());
                assertEquals(0, letter.getMinOcc());
                assertEquals(0, letter.getMaxOcc());
                correct = letter.getCorrect();
                incorrect = letter.getIncorrect();

                assertEquals(false, correct.contains(0));
                assertEquals(false, correct.contains(1));
                assertEquals(false, correct.contains(2));
                assertEquals(false, correct.contains(3));
                assertEquals(false, correct.contains(4));

                assertEquals(false, incorrect.contains(0));
                assertEquals(false, incorrect.contains(1));
                assertEquals(false, incorrect.contains(2));
                assertEquals(false, incorrect.contains(3));
                assertEquals(false, incorrect.contains(4));
```

As you can see, I would have to pass many parameters. One for each boolean, the min value, max value, the character, and the Letter object itself.

Comment: Well for starters there's `assertFalse(arg)` instead of `assertEquals(false, arg)`. You could consider Hamcrest. It gives you declarative matchers like `assertThat(correct, containsNone(0, 1, 2, 3, 4))` (just pseudocode, but you get the idea).

Comment: Also just a standard for-loop works here. for i = 0 to 4, containing 2 assertions, one for correct, one for incorrect.

Comment: which method are you actually testing here? `.getLetter`? Maybe you should consider to use `Letter.equals` then (so `assertEquals(expectedLetter, letter)`) - and if you want to test something else, consider splitting it up into multiple tests.